# Excel add Row Grouping using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

I have below csv file, I want to import into excel and add the row grouping for the child items using powershell. I was able open the file and format the cell. Not sure how to add row grouping.

**Data**

```
name,,
one,,
,value1,value2
,value3 ,value4
two,,
,value4,sevalue4
,value5,sevalue5
,value6,sevalue6
,value7,sevalue7
three,,
,value8,sevalue8
,value9,sevalue9
,value10,sevalue10
,value11,sevalue11
```

I want to convert like this in excel.

[image]

Here is the code I have it to open it in excel.

```
$a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$a.visible = $True 

$b = $a.Workbooks.Open("C:\shared\c1.csv")

$c = $b.Worksheets.Item(1)
$d = $c.Cells(1,1)
$d.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
$d.Font.ColorIndex = 11
$d.Font.Bold = $True

$b.Save("C:\shared\c1.xlsx")
```

How do I add row grouping for this data?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Logic Applied:**

Group all the **consecutive rows** for which the value in column `A` is blank

In the following code, I have opened a CSV file, made the required grouping as per the data shared by you and saved it. While saving it, because of the row grouping, I was not able to save it in csv format. So, I had to change the format to a normal workbook. But, it works.

**Code**

```
$objExl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExl.visible = $true
$objExl.DisplayAlerts = $false
$strPath = "C:\Users\gurmansingh\Documents\a.csv"    #Enter the path of csv
$objBook = $objExl.Workbooks.open($strPath)
$objSheet = $objBook.Worksheets.item(1)
$intRowCount = $objSheet.usedRange.Rows.Count
for($i=1; $i -le $intRowCount; $i++)
{
    if($objSheet.Cells.Item($i,1).text -like "")
    {
        $startRow = $i
        for($j=$i+1; $j -le $intRowCount; $j++)
        {
            if($objSheet.cells.Item($j,1).text -ne "" -or $j -eq $intRowCount)
            {
                $endRow = $j-1
                if($j -eq $intRowCount)
                {
                    $endRow = $j
                }
                break
            }
        }
        $str = "A"+$startRow+":A"+$endRow
        $objSheet.Range($str).Rows.Group()
        $i=$j
    }
}
$objBook.SaveAs("C:\Users\gurmansingh\Documents\b",51)        #saving in a different format.
$objBook.Close()
$objExl.Quit()
```

**Before:**

```
a.csv
```

[image]

**Output after running the code:**

```
b.xlsx
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out how easy it is to do using my Excel PowerShell module.

`Install-Module ImportExcel`

https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues/556#issuecomment-469897886